# Regex Matches not working as excepted

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to group the following string into three groups.

```
0:0:Awesome:awesome
```

That being "**0**", "**0**" and "**Awesome:awesome**"

Using this regular expression:

```
^([0-9]+)\:([0-9]*)\:(.*)$
```

It works fine on online regex services: http://rubular.com/r/QePxt57EwU

But it seems like .NET doesn't agree.
[Picture of Regex problem from Visual Studio http://xs.to/image-3F8A_4BA916BD.jpg](http://xs.to/image-3F8A_4BA916BD.jpg)

Comment: Rubular uses Ruby's regexp engine, which is not the same as .NET's. For this pattern, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work, but just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Adding to what Daniel said, a great tool for testing .NET regular expressions is Expresso, though testing yours seems to work fine for me.    http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The `MatchCollection` contains the results of applying the regular expression to the source string iteratively.** In your case there is only 1 match - so the results are correct. What you have are **multiple captures** within the match. This is what you want to compare against - not the number of matches.

```
MatchCollection matches = RegEx.Matches("0:0:Awesome:awesome",
                                        "^([0-9]+)\:([0-9]*)\:(.*)$");

if( matches.Count != 1 && matches[0].Captures.Count != 3 )
  //...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to access the matched groups the following could help you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pattern = "^([0-9]+)\\:([0-9]*)\\:(.*)$";

            var matches = Regex.Match("0:0:Awesome:awesome", pattern);

            foreach (var match in matches.Groups)
                Console.WriteLine(match);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this regexp would suit

```
(?<nums>\d+\:?)+(?<rest>.*)
```

Then you can get the groupings for 'num' and 'rest' together as shown

```
public Regex MyRegex = new Regex(
      "^(?<nums>\\d+\\:?)+(?<rest>.*)$",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
MatchCollection ms = MyRegex.Matches(InputText);
```

Where `InputText` would contain the sample '0:0:Awesome:Awesome'